# $\int_0^a x^s \,dx$ converges iff $s>-1$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

$a \in\mathbb{R}, a >0, s \in\mathbb{R}$

1. $\int_0^a x^s \,dx$ converges iff $s>-1$.
2. $\int_a^\infty x^s \,dx$ converges iff $s<-1$.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward FTC problem; what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int_{0}^a x^s\ dx= \frac {x^{s+1}}{s+1}|_0^a$

We don't have a problem for $0<a<\infty.$  We might have a problem evaluating at $0$ depending on the value of $s.$

if $\lim_\limits{y\to 0^+} \int_y^a x^s \ dx$ exists.  Then we are in good shape.

$\lim_\limits {y\to 0+} \frac {y^{s+1}}{s+1} = 0$ if $s> -1$

Now do something similar for the second half.

Answer (score 0):

$\int_0^a x^sdx=[\frac{x^{s+1}}{s+1}]_0^a$. If $s\le -1$ then $x^{s+1}\to\infty$ for $x\to 0$.
$\int_a^{\infty} x^sdx=[\frac{x^{s+1}}{s+1}]_a^{\infty}$ and if $s\ge -1$ then $x^{s+1}\to \infty$ for $x\to \infty$.